# UIDocument openWithCompletionHandler: forces NSMetadataQuery to update

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I’m trying to use iCloud and an app is listening to `NSMetadataQuery` updates subscribing to  `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification`.

When the app receives notification I read some iCloud `UIDocument` files using `openWithCompletionHandler:` but that call causes `NSMetadataQuery` to notify me of updates again and so app gets in an endless cycle `update > read > update > read > …`

Should `openWithCompletionHandler:` behave this way? What can I do to prevent it from such a cycle?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue too, and it seems, like the answer to your question

> Should openWithCompletionHandler: behave this way?

is "Yes". I can just assume it, but it sounds reasonable, that when you do `openWithCompletionHandler:` the block is called, when all the data is loaded. However with `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification` you can trace downloading progress (e.g. percentage of data loading before your openWithHandler block is called).

My solution so far is:

- watch for notification updates of `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusCurrent`
- disableUpdates when I suppose to open the document
- enableUpdates for the query inside of block of the document opening

Due to the fact, that my query is watching a single file, I'm not afraid to lose notifications, which may be skipped during one document opening. It might be not the case if there are several documents watched, but I don't know how to solve it better

Answer (score 0):

Should `openWithCompletionHandler`: behave this way?

It is not correct. `NSMetadataQuery` notify updates. It causes by:

- (`NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification`) , it means that iCloud update data (uploading file 
  from sandbox to iCloud or downloading file from iCloud to sandbox)
- When you call `[_query startQuery]`, it call `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification` just one to notify data in iCloud. After that, when data has update `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification`

I think this circle is correct because when you have new data from iCloud, you should update data in your screen.

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: But when I just access (open) new data I get a NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification call. Just because I call openWithCompletionHandler:

Comment: Let's test: You wait until all data is got. After that you open 1 UIDocument by openWithCompletionHandler. I'm sure that NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification will not call.